# Want to set innodb configuration variables setting properly ? want to know what variable size will best for mysql 5.5

Tags: mysql

I used Mysql 5.5.57 and used innodb
Currency I face performance related issues due to which our system gets crashed.
and got many errors like lockwait time out and deadlock problems on many tables.
I trying to solve that.
but i think if i change my innodb configuration default setting then also system performance gets increased but i dont know what type of variable needs to change so please help me

below is our default innodb configuration setting:

The below is the settings in my.cnf:

```
innodb_file_format=barracuda
innodb_file_format_max=barracuda
innodb_file_per_table=1
query-cache-size    = 64M
thread_cache_size   = 8
default-time-zone = '+05:30'
query_cache_limit   = 10M
character_set_server=utf8mb4
collation_server=utf8mb4_general_ci
innodb_thread_concurrency=8
key_buffer_size=183500800
group_concat_max_len=50000
innodb_log_file_size=178257920
#innodb_lock_wait_timeout=150

innodb_buffer_pool_size=134 MB
innodb_thread_concurrency=8
innodb_thread_sleep_delay=10000
innodb_concurrency_tickets=500
innodb lock_wait_time_out=150
```

We have 132GB Ram on the server with 2 processors and each has 6 cores.
16GB should be more than enough for MySql.

please help to set proper variables size for each parameter i provided here

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you read this atrticle https://www.percona.com/blog/2013/09/20/innodb-performance-optimization-basics-updated/

You will find example for each variable there, i think this is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I've got a significant performance boost by setting

```
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=0
innodb_buffer_pool_size=2G
innodb_log_file_size=256M
innodb_log_buffer_size=8M
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=1
```

Specifically, `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=0` speeds up loading a dump file from minutes to seconds! This setting is not recommended for "mission-critical" environments but is pretty fine for a development machine.